# Share REST API session cookies with SFAuthenticationSession or SFSafariViewController

Tags: uiwebview, wkwebview, sfsafariviewcontroller, nshttpcookiestorage, sfauthenticationsession

Actually, I'm calling REST API services using ***NSURLSession*** and I get the session cookies which provided headers. Now I want to share the same cookies with ***SFAuthenticationSession*** or ***SFSafariViewController*** and load the web page without login.

**My Question:** Share API cookies and load the web page without login.

***Please refer below code to get the cookies from NSURLSession:***

```
 NSArray * all = [NSHTTPCookie cookiesWithResponseHeaderFields:[reponse allHeaderFields] forURL:url];
 [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] setCookies:all forURL:url mainDocumentURL:nil];
```